# Google Voice SMS messages not showing up in Hangouts

Tags: google-voice, google-hangouts

I'm using Google Voice to send text messages to someone.  I've chosen to send the messages through Hangouts. The messages are being sent successfully and the recipient gets them but they don't show up in the chat log in hangouts.

However, they are showing up in the stock Messages app. Shouldn't the messages be listed in both apps?

Comment: Android allows only one app at the time to have access to private messages (SMS). Change your standard SMS application to Hangsout in `Settings->More...->Default SMS app`.

Comment: It currently is set to hangouts. I do use hangouts as my default sms app and have been for months. If I send messages through Hangouts interface, the sent messages show in the log just fine. Its like Google Now just doesn't honor my hangouts selection and just uses the stock Messages app

Comment: Hmm, seems like an issue of Google Now then, maybe search on the issue tracker (if they have one) for that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too. But I went to Settings > Apps > Messaging and disabled the stock messenger app. Then everything goes through hangouts. But I ended up just going back to the old Google Voice app bc I couldn't get my phone calls to work right with Hangouts. It wasn't forwarding right, so I missed calls, and it wouldn't use my Google Voice voicemail system (it kept using my stock VM system). If you have any help with these, please let me know.